# Django - Multiple custom models on the same form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using Django 2.1 and PostgreSQL.
My problem is that I'm trying to create a form to edit two different models at the same time. This models are related with a FK, and every example that I see is with the user and profile models, but with that I can't replicate what I really need.

My models simplified to show the related information about them are:

```
# base model for Campaigns.
class CampaignBase(models.Model):
    ....
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    ....

# define investment campaign made on a project.
class InvestmentCampaign(models.Model):
    ....
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(CampaignBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    description = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        max_length=25000,
    )
    ....
```

And the form that I want to create is one that includes the `end_date` of the FK `CampaignBase`, and the `Description` from the `InvestmentCampaign`.

Now I have this `UpdateView` to edit the InvestmentCampaign, and I need to adapt to my actual needs, that are also update the `CampaignBase` model:

```
class ProjectEditInvestmentCampaignView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'webplatform/project_edit_investment_campaign.html'
    model = InvestmentCampaign
    form_class = CreateInvestmentCampaignForm
    success_message = 'Investment campaign updated!'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('project-update-investment-campaign', args=(self.kwargs['project'], self.kwargs['pk']))

    # Make the view only available for the users with current fields
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        # here you can make your custom validation for any particular user
        if request.user != self.object.campaign.project.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # Set field as current user
    def form_valid(self, form):
        campaign = InvestmentCampaign.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['campaign'])
        form.instance.campaign = campaign
        form.instance.history_change_reason = 'Investment campaign updated'
        return super(ProjectEditInvestmentCampaignView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        project = Project.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['project'])
        context = super(ProjectEditInvestmentCampaignView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['project'] = project
        return context
```

My forms are:

```
class CreateCampaignBaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CampaignBase
        fields = ('end_date',)
        widgets = {
            'end_date': DateTimePickerInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(CreateCampaignBaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # evade all labels and help text to appear when using "as_crispy_tag"
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper._help_text_inline = True


class CreateInvestmentCampaignForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InvestmentCampaign
        fields = ('description')
        widgets = {
            'description': SummernoteWidget(attrs={'summernote': {
                'placeholder': 'Add some details of the Investment Campaign here...'}}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(CreateInvestmentCampaignForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # evade all labels and help text to appear when using "as_crispy_tag"
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper._help_text_inline = True
```

I've read everywhere that the best way of doing this is using function based views, and call each of the forms that I have and then do the validation. the thing is that I don't know how can I populate the fields with the right object in both forms, and also, I don't know how to do the equivalent of the get_context_data nor getting the `self` arguments to do the equivalent of the `get_success_url` (because with function based views I only have the request attr so I can't access the kwargs).

I've seen some people using the [django-betterforms](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but again, the only examples are with the auth and profile models and I don't see the way to replicate that with my own models.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If the only thing you want to change is one field `end_date` on `BaseCampaign`, just add that as an additional field on your `CreateInvestmentCampaignForm` and in your `form.valid()` method, after saving the form, set the value on the associated campaign: `inv_campaign = form.save(); inv_campaign.campaign.end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']; inv_campaign.campaign.save()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only thing you want to change is one field `end_date` on `BaseCampaign`, then you should use just one form. Just add `end_date` as an additional field (e.g. `forms.DateTimeField()`) on your `CreateInvestmentCampaignForm` and in your `form.valid()` method, after saving the form, set the value on the associated campaign:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    inv_campaign = form.save(commit=False)
    inv_campaign.campaign.end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
    inv_campaign.campaign.save()
    inv_campaign.history_change_reason = ...
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here's how to add `end_date` to your form and initialize it correctly:

```
class CreateInvestmentCampaignForm(ModelForm):
    end_date = forms.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = InvestmentCampaign
        fields = ('description')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.campaign:
            self.fields['end_date'].initial = self.instance.campaign.end_date
```

Comment: But with this when I will not see the actual value of the `end_date` field populated on the form, you know? I will have the field always empty and the user will need to put the `end_date` every time. I need to have all the fields populated on the template so the user won't need to fill it every time it needs to modify something from the description.

Comment: Then you add the value to initial data. That’s what `get_inital_data` does.

Comment: `get_initial_data` on the form or on the view? on the form it appears me that I can add a `def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):`

Comment: On the view. Not sure when `get_initial_for_field` gets called in a `Form`. I'd then rather do it directly in the `__init__()` method by setting `self.fields['end_date'].initial = ...`.

Comment: so I have to just create a simple Form, not a ModelForm, because the ModelForm only let me add fields on that model for what I've seen. If that's correct, the relation between a simple form and an UpdateView is the same, right? I don't have to add anything else than the `def __init__()`on the view popuating both model fields.

Comment: No you can always add any field (non model field) on a ModelForm just by defining it as class attribute as you would for a plain `Form`.

Comment: And you should keep a ModelForm otherwise your UpdateView can’t update the instance of the form.

Comment: Now I added on the modelform this field `end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)`, but only with that when rendering on the template as `{{ form.end_date }}` the result rendered is this: `<django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField>`. The field is not rendered as it should be. Also, debugging the template I've seen that the `end_date` is inside the `form`, not inside `form.fields` as the `description` field (which is well rendered)

Comment: Because you're using `models.DateTimeField` instead of using a form field. Use `forms.DateTimeInput()`

Comment: now template is rendering `<django.forms.widgets.DateTimeInput object at 0x112827fd0>`.

Comment: sorry, was a bit too fast. As I said, it should be form field and what you're using is a form widget as you can see from the output. You can look it up [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/)

Comment: I've seen your updated answer and works perfect, but also got the answer following your advice of adding the init data on the view. So I'll mark your answer as correct and also edit my question with the answer I've got thanks to your help so people can check both answers and then use the one they prefer. thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: @PolFrances If you have an alternative answer, add it as an answer (you are allowed to answer your own question), don't add it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation on the answer of @dirkgroten, I've developed what worked for me and what I'm actually using, but I market his answer as correct because his code is also functional.

So, meanwhile he is initiating the values on the form, I'm using the view to do that by adding a `def get_initial(self):` and also adding the validation on the `def form_valid(self, form):`:

On the view:

```
...

    def get_initial(self):
        """
        Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
        """
        initial = super(ProjectEditInvestmentCampaignView, self).get_initial()
        initial['end_date'] = self.object.campaign.end_date
        return initial
...
    # Set field as current user
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.history_change_reason = 'Investment campaign updated'
        is_valid = super(ProjectEditInvestmentCampaignView, self).form_valid(form)
        if is_valid:
            # the base campaign fields
            campaign = form.instance.campaign
            campaign.end_date = form.cleaned_data.get("end_date")
            campaign.save()
        return is_valid
```

And on the form I just added the `end_date` field:

```
class CreateInvestmentCampaignForm(forms.ModelForm):
    end_date = forms.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = InvestmentCampaign
        fields = ('description',)
        widgets = {
            'description': SummernoteWidget(attrs={'summernote': {
                'placeholder': 'Add some details of the Investment Campaign here...'}}),
            'end_date': DateTimePickerInput(),  # format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(CreateInvestmentCampaignForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # evade all labels and help text to appear when using "as_crispy_tag"
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper._help_text_inline = True
```